# Python - How to remove reference to an object without copying it

Tags: object, copy, ray

I have fallowing problem:
In Ray software, it is needed to remove all references to an object, to release memory that is used by the object. So, I need to:

```
def some_func():
    # results is very complex object with array, lists, dictionaries
    results = ray.get(hash_for_given_job)
    result_copy = copy.deepcopy(results)
    del results

    return results_copy
```

Nevertheless, it causes that the object will occupy twice of memory at some point in time. Therefore increasing RAM memory usage. How to remove a reference, and return an object, without copying it ?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect you don't actually need to deep copy `results`. Objects in the ray object store are immutable. When you call `ray.get()` you're already creating a copy of the object, thus if you do something like

```
    results = ray.get(hash_for_given_job)
    results_copy = ray.get(hash_for_given_job)
    results.a = "hello" 
    assert results_copy.a != results_copy.b
```

This would hold true regardless of whether `results` and `results_copy` are in the same function, different tasks, different machines, etc.